# Azure Analysis Services: refresh from Excel workbook?

Tags: ssas, azure-analysis-services

Using a Tabular model in Azure Analysis Services is there a way to refresh data out of an Excel workbook?

When working in VS2019 to build the tabular model I can of course map a path to a network drive and pull in the data from Excel.

What happens once it is deployed to Azure?  It won't have access to UNC paths anymore, right?  Even though our UNC is on a VM in Azure?

Do I have to get the data out of Excel and into a different data repository?

I thought I could use OneDrive like you can for Power BI but that does not appear to be supported.

Thanks!